# Facebook feed dialog: allow user to select destination page or group

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using a Facebook feed dialog through JavaScript:

```
var p = {
method: 'feed',
    name: 'Title',
    caption: 'Subtitle - 26/02/2013',
    description: 'My text',
    link: window.location.href
};
FB.ui(p)
```

Is there a way to allow the user select the destination page for the feed ? 
Usually the resulting dialog allows user to post a message on his own wall. I would like to enable destination select, like:

> on my wall or on my page or into a group

With subsequent page or group selection, as happens on Facebook site.
Is there a way to show this kind of selection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in share dialog included in the JavaScript SDK doesn't include this functionality. You will instead need to create your own dropdown with the options you want and then have the share button underneath. You will then need to find the value of this dropdown and add it to the `to` parameter of the `FB.ui` function:

```
<select id="to_user">
 <option value="{user_id}">My wall</option>
 <option value="{page_id}">My page</option>
 <option value="{group_id}">My group</option>
</select>

<script>
var p = {
    method: 'feed',
    to: $('#to_user').val(),
    name: 'Title',
    caption: 'Subtitle - 26/02/2013',
    description: 'My text',
    link: window.location.href
};
FB.ui(p);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the feed dialog box for selecting the destination.Please check
    http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Did you mean the "to" parameter ? This allow to select the destination user if you know this before show the dialog. In my case I don't know who is the user for the feed dialog, so I don't use the neither "from" or "to" parameter and the current (logged) user is selected (and this works fine). I would like to have in the dialog panel an option or a combo that enables the current user to choose the destination between its wall, its page or a generic group.