# Facebook Javascript SDK Feed Dialog showing blank window

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK to post on my page, i've already read something about this here: [Facebook feed dialog: allow user to select destination page or group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083668/facebook-feed-dialog-allow-user-to-select-destination-page-or-group) so I've been using this code so far:

```
$("button#shareOn").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var _parentForm=$(this).parents('form:first');
    var _pageSelect=_parentForm.find("select[name='pagesList']");
    var _pID=_parentForm.find("#pID").attr('value');
    var _vURL=_parentForm.find("#_vURL").attr('value');
    
    FB.ui({
        app_id:app_id,
        method: 'feed',
        from: _pageSelect.val(),
        name: 'Title',
        caption: 'Subtitle - 26/02/2013',
        description: 'My text',
        link: _vURL,
    },function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });

});
```

Where `_pageSelect.val()` is the ID of the page in which I'm trying to post, `_vURL` is the url ( youtube link ) which I want to share... The problem is that when I click on the button, a window opens up, but's actually blank.

By opening Google Chrome's dev console, sometimes I see a 500 Internal Server error related to that window and sometimes it only comes up totally empty, but I can't figure out what is actually causing it.
I've also tried `urlencode` the url from PHP or `encodeURIComponent` from Javascript, but nothing as changed at all.

Sometimes the window comes up only with Title, Subtitle and Description, so I guess the link should be the error, but I knew that Facebook JS SDK used to write `Link not properly formatted` or something like `API error (100)`.

## UPDATE

It seems that Feed dialog has started collaborating, but still not working as expected. This is the updated code:

```
$("button#shareOn[name='shareVideo']").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var _parentForm=$(this).parents('form:first');
    var _pageSelect=_parentForm.find("select[name='pagesList']");
    var _pID=_parentForm.find("#pID").attr('value');
    var _vURL=_parentForm.find("#_vURL").attr('value');
    var options={
        app_id:app_id,
        method:'feed',
        from:_pageSelect.val(),
        link:_vURL,
        caption:'test'
    }
    
    console.log(options);
    
    FB.ui( options, function(response){});

});
```

The window is opening, but sometimes it's blank and sometimes shows a link, which is not the url of the video, but it's just `www.youtube.com`. I've been trying with the Facebook URL Debugger and it's showing me that the URL which I'm using is actually right. But feed dialog just doesn't work

Comment: Feed dialog has been deprecated for quite a while now. Use the Share dialog, or (should the functionality that offers not suffice) make your post via API.

Comment: I'm using the feed dialog, which is only discouraged by Facebook, not deprecated, because with the Share Dialog I can't post on my page, but only on my profile. Anyway, the Facebook docs says that if I want users to post something, I can't let them post without editing the content, so they encourage to use Share dialogs, which aren't suitable for what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've got the answer, which isn't really what I was expecting, but at least it works. As the Facebook docs aren't pointing to this, I've found the `sharer` method, which I call in a Javascript function.
So, this is the code:

```
$("button#shareOn[name='shareVideo']").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var _parentForm=$(this).parents('form:first');
    var _pageSelect=_parentForm.find("select[name='pagesList']");
    var _pID=_parentForm.find("#pID").attr('value');
    var _vURL=_parentForm.find("#_vURL").attr('value');
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + 400 + ",width=" + 300 + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";

    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((300 / 2) + 10);
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((400 / 2) + 50);

    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(_vURL),'sharer', windowFeatures);
    return false;
});
```

By the way, I don't like this method, but it seems like the only way to accomplish what i was trying to do. Now I just need to know how to get the result of the sharing function ( if the post was shared or not ).

Hope this will help someone :)