# Writing a comment onto a 3rd party facebook wall via website link

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Really wracking my brains about how to do this but i basically dont even know where to start.

Basically twitter has functionality that allows a link to open a twitter box that a user can populate and then post directly onto a chosen twitter feed:

https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#mention

Its super simple, all it requires is changing the URL parameters of the target link.

Im trying to do something similar with facebook. Ideally a link clicked on my site would open a facebook page with a prompt for user to type their comment and login to post to the 3rd party wall. I definitely do not want to be handling any FB authentication on my end as i imagine this would be far beyond my rather novice coding abilities.

An alternative would be to capture the comment with a text box on my end and then pass this through to facebook to write onto the wall.

Ive trawled the net and stack exchange looking for solutions but most seem to be geared to putting a comment on the users wall rather than a 3rd party.

Honestly im not super active on any social media anyway so my knowledge of how they function is quite limited. If anyone could give me a steer and some possible solutions (or alternatively just out and out that it is impossible) that would be fantastic.

Comment: Alternatively, if there was a way to use the "share" or "send" functionality while defaulting the recipient, removing the option to add other recipients and maybe altering the ghost text in the comment box slightly, this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript), and invoke the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3) using that.
The feed dialog has a [`to` parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3#params) into which you can fill the Facebook ID of the profile that you would like the user to post to. However, the profile who's ID you fill in there must have authorized the same app as the one that you initialized the SDK for. That means this approach is likely impractical.
In any event, [here's a piece of example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083668/).

If you would like to use graph API to post to a profile's timeline (using the [`profile-ID/feed` `POST` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed)), you'll have to implement Facebook Login as well. However, since Graph API v2.0 is mandatory for all apps now, you can only find those profile IDs of people who have also authorized the same app.
This is probably even less practical for you, given that you don't want to implement Facebook login.

As far as I can see, these are your only options to achieve what you are looking  for at this time.